# Custom catch-all parameter in routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I recently want to have a special routing rule : {*whatever}/details/{Id}/{itemName}

I know an exception will be thrown once I run the application. In my application, for example my url pattern is www.domain.com/root/parent/child/.../child/details/30/itemname

but the current routing doesnot support this. How can custom the routing handler to make it work?

Comment: You are asking for restful routing of (arbitrary) deeply nested resources correct? Like a filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

### A class has been written that supports this

I've written such a class that can handle catch-all segment anywhere in the URL. There's quite some code to it, but it works as expected and I've used it on a real life project.

[Check it out yourself](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html) and see if it fulfils your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is... how will it know when to stop?

the {*whatever} segment will match:

```
/foo/
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/details/4/moreFoo
/foo/bar/andmore/details/4/moreFoo
```

Because the catch-all parameter includes anything, it will never stop.

The only way to implement this would be to create a different route for each place you use details...

eg:

```
games/details/{id}/{itemName}
widgets/details/{id}/{itemName}
books/details/{id}/{itemName}
```

Of course, that is already provided in the default {controller}/{action}/{id} route

Comment: It can. GetRouteData parses the route from the beginning. When it comes to a greedy catch-all parameter it reverses parsing and parses from the back. When it comes back to the greedy catch-all parameter it pust all remaining content into it. I don't see a problem here. This way catch all can be anywhere in the URL as long as **there's at most one greedy catch-all parameter**.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this. Has it been this way since .Net Routing was first introduced?

Comment: it doesn't work out of the box though. but I've pointed out that technically there's no limitation of not having a catch-all anywhere in the URL. And I've also written a custom `Route` class that supports this. And it's been used ona real life project as well so I can tell you that it works. http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look at extending the System.Web.Routing.RouteBase class and override the GetRouteData() method. With it you can look at the requested url and decide if matches your pattern and if so construct and return a new instance of RouteData that points to the controller and action that you want to handle the request. Otherwise if you don't match the requested url you return null.

See the following for examples:

[Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework
 By Steve Sanderson](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xb3a1xTSfZgC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=asp.net+mvc+Custom+RouteBase&source=bl&ots=J9GeSapcjr&sig=T_dVgDpETzHwvxKm0iPP-7AZIFc&hl=en&ei=7dsqSt62DaCJtgesp9HGCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#PPA249,M1)

[Custom RouteBase](http://blogs.securancy.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx)